# How to write this MYSQL query with multiple JOIN and OR in RoR ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
rails --version
2.3.16
ruby --version
1.8.7
```

Models:

```
class AToB
    belongs_to :a
    belongs_to :b
    default_scope :include => [:a, :b]
end
class A
    has_many :a_to_bs
    has_many :bs, :through => :a_to_bs
    named_scope :twos, :conditions => { :var => 2 }
    named_scope :buzzed, :conditions => { :fizz => ['buzz'] }
end
class B
    has_many :a_to_bs
    has_many :as, :through => :a_to_bs
end
```

MYSQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id), COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
FROM a_to_b
INNER JOIN a on a.id = a_to_b.a_id
INNER JOIN b on b.id = a_to_b.b_id
WHERE (a.var = 2 AND a.fizz in ('buzz') AND
       (b.foo = TRUE OR b.bar = TRUE OR (b.moo = TRUE AND a_to_b.goo = FALSE))
      )
```

Will also need this variation

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.id), COUNT(DISTINCT c.id)
FROM a_to_b
INNER JOIN a on a.id = a_to_b.a_id
INNER JOIN b on b.id = a_to_b.b_id
WHERE (a.var = 2 AND a.fizz in ('buzz') AND
       NOT (b.foo = TRUE OR b.bar = TRUE OR (b.moo = TRUE AND a_to_b.goo = FALSE))
      )
```

I've already googled countless simpler examples, read [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html#sum), etc. to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kinda worked:

```
scope = A.twos.buzzed
scope.count(:joins => { :b => :a_to_b }, :conditions => "b.foo = TRUE OR b.bar = TRUE OR (b.moo = TRUE AND a_to_b.goo = FALSE)")
```

Going to test a bit more before I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try answering this question. For example your models are as follow in Rails:

```
#a.rb
class A < ActiveRecord::Base 
  attr_accessible :var, :fizz
  has_many :a_to_bs
end

#b.rb
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :foo, :bar, :moo
  has_many :a_to_bs
end

#a_to_b.rb
class AToB < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :goo, :a_id, :b_id, :a, :b
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
end
```

A typical query for the first one would be:

```
records = AToB.where("a.var = ? AND a.fizz in (?) AND (b.foo = ? OR b.bar = ? OR 
          (b.moo = ? AND a_to_b.goo = ?))", 2, 'buzz', true, true, true, false)
```

And for the second one it would be:

```
records = AToB.where("a.var = ? AND a.fizz in (?) AND NOT (b.foo = ? OR b.bar = ? OR
         (b.moo = ? AND a_to_b.goo = ?))", 2, 'buzz', true, true, true, false)
```

The answer is true assuming the queries you mentioned are correct.

Comment: This wouldn't work for me. I added some information about what the models are set to, including some named scopes. Also, I can't use `.where()`, as I'm not using Rails 3.